# Why is Oxygen compulsory for free radical reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is presence of oxygen compulsory for free radical mechanism? Can it take place in presence of any other element?

Comment: Other elements can form free radicals. Any diatomic gas would do.

Comment: [AIBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azobisisobutyronitrile) is a common radical initiator, and it contains no oxygen.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such condition that oxygen must be present to generate free radicals. Chlorine forms free radicals, and so do many organic molecules. In fact the presence of oxygen is bad for free radical reactions.